# ServiceStack RedisMqServer: No way to add or remove channels in runtime?

Tags: redis, servicestack, publish-subscribe

My, already "legacy" by now, implementation of a pub/sub solution using ServiceStack quickly ran out of clients, when it reached the 20 client limit.

We do something like:

```
_redisConsumer = MqClientFactory.Instance.GetRedisClient(); // Returns a IRedisClient
_subscription = _redisConsumer.CreateSubscription();
_subscription.OnSubscribe = channel => CoreLog.Instance.Info($"Subscription started on {eventChannelName}");
_subscription.OnUnSubscribe = channel => CoreLog.Instance.Warning($"Unsubscribed from {eventChannelName}");

_subscription.OnMessage = (channel, msg) =>
{
    try
    {
        onMessageReceived(CoreRequestJsonEnvelope.CreateCoreRequestFromJson(msg));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CoreLog.Instance.Exception(ex);
    }
};

// Since it blocks execution, we put this in a Task:
Task.Run(() => 
{
    try
    {
        _subscription.SubscribeToChannels(eventChannelName); // blocking
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    { 
    }
});
```

and when we have enough different channels to listen too, it runs out.

I then thought, that maybe instead of taking a new IRedisClient for each subscription, I could use the same IRedisClient for all of them, so:

```
_redisConsumer = mySavedRedisClient;
...
```

but that returns `Unknown reply on multi-request` after a few seconds/executions.

Lastly, I looked at the `RedisPubSubServer`, but it seems that I need to specify the channels in the constructor, and I cannot change after that. I do need to add and remove channels in runtime, and channels are not known from start.

- What is the recommended approach?
- Is it to increaase the Max-limit and continue as before?
- Is it to use RedisPubSub, but how to handle dynamic channels?
- What does "unknown reply on multi-request" actually mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what 20 client limit you're referring to & how the client limit is dependent on channels or subscribers, but if this is your App own limit than sounds like increasing it would be the easiest solution.

ServiceStack.Redis doesn't support changing the subscribed channels after a subscription has started. Instead of managing the `IRedisSubscription` yourself you may want to consider [ServiceStack.Redis Managed Pub/Sub Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#managed-pubsub-server) which manages the background subscription thread with added resiliency and support for auto retries.

Whilst you can't change the subscribed channels at runtime, you can modify the modify the `Channels` collection and restart the subscription to create a new subscription to the updated channels list, e.g:

```
var pubSub = new RedisPubSubServer(clientsManager, chan1);
pubSub.Start();

//...

pubSub.Channels = new[] { chan1, chan2 };
pubSub.Restart();
```

Otherwise depending on your use-case you may be able to [subscribe to a channel pattern](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe) which allows you to subscribe to a multiple dynamic channels matching wildcard channel pattern:

```
var pubSub = new RedisPubSubServer(clientsManager) {
       ChannelsMatching = new[] { "chan:*" }
    }
    .Start();
```

Where it will handle any messages clients send that matches the channel pattern.

Comment: Ah, .Restart I missed. I made a more cumbersome workaround that seems to work, but that seems a lot easier. Regarding the 20-client-limit; its a default limit of the PooledRedisClientManager; because of the first not-so-good implementation, we take one IRedisClient for each channel, and then manually subscribe to it, meaning that the 20 client default limit will be reached as soon as we have 20 channels or more.

Comment: @Ted You can extend it with `RedisConfig.DefaultMaxPoolSize` or switch to use [RedisManagerPool](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redismanagerpool) where any connections that exceed the poolsize will be created & disposed outside of the pool.

Comment: Hmm, `string[] Channels { get; }`, so I can't assign anything to it. I have version 5.8.0, maybe you made a public setter late ron?

Comment: Ah, the concrete impl `RedisPubSubServer` has a setter for Channels, but the interface does not? https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisPubSubServer.cs